# huge amount of data in tableview Cell Titanium

Tags: tableview, titanium-mobile

I have data base which contains the 4000 rows.
and i want to display this data with tableview on android.

but device shows memory warning.

do we can reuse cells like we use in iPhone development.

Please suggest the good way. so that bulk amount data won't crash on android devices.

Answer (score 0):

Add a search field on the Top of the Table and only display about 50 Entries. Then if the User Scrolls further and reaches <10 Cells you are appending the Table with another 50 Entries.
But you still have to limit the overall Count of Cells. No body needs such many rows. Even my iPhone Crashes if i scroll up like 6 months of conversation with my Girlfriend in "WhatsApp" ;)

--> Example: https://gist.github.com/810391